# Would Twemproxy rebalance after adding more redis servers?

Tags: redis, twemproxy

We are planning to use redis with twemproxy. Initially, we have two redis servers, but will add more redis servers down the road. I'm wondering if twemproxy will rebalance the redis servers after we have added more redis servers. Or should we start with the expected number of instances on the two redis servers to begin with and later on migrate instances to the new servers after we add them? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

twemporxy do not rebalance data.

you should deploy more instances, then migrate.

this is easy to do with redis-mgr ( https://github.com/idning/redis-mgr)

read this: https://github.com/idning/redis-mgr/blob/master/doc/scalablity.rst